# AnguarJS DateTimePicker That Can Automatically Set Current Time (h,m,s)?

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker

Looking for an AngularJS DateTimePicker (not a date picker) that can automatically set the H:M:S.

For example, if you choose March 22, 2017 (03/22/2017) and it is currently 4:30 in the evening, you can set the date and the time will be set for you as follows:

```
3/22/2017 4:30:00 PM
```

Any idea as to which AngularjS Date Time Picker is the best for such functionality?

UPDATE: Probably should have stated before, but we have used almost every AngularJS datetimepicker out there, and are forced to provide our own hours and minutes.

Makato, thank you for the heads up.

Comment: You're asking for a library, and that's not permitted here; you'd get a list of possible libraries to use with no concrete way to ascertain which is the best for *your* specific needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker, you just set the format you want to use, in this case:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" datetime-picker="dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a" ng-model="myDate" />`

I create a plunker with a functional example: https://plnkr.co/edit/Aygll8dlUA6IglT7rFuD?p=preview